# Elucidate two assertions in angularjs patterns

Tags: angularjs

We will often find ourself repeating the same event handling code over and
over in our controllers and it is better to move the code to a base controller. 
We can then inherit that functionality by using the $controller service to add 
the base controller's properties and functions on to the controller's scope,

as shown in the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function($scope) {
 // methods to be inherited by all controllers
 // go here
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
 // this call to $controller adds the ParentCtrl's methods
 // and properties to the ChildCtrl's scope
 $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
 // ChildCtrl's methods and properties go here
});
```

Can anybody tell us clearly and give us 2 examples which can elucidate 
the following two assertions

## Assertion 1:

If we have redundant event handlers that need to be unregistered
when a view is destroyed, we can ensure that the code to unregister the event
handlers is executed when the controller is destroyed by including the redundant
code in the base controller and using the $on method to execute it when the
$destroy message is broadcasted.

## Assertion 2:

However, if we were to use the pattern of
inheriting functionality by embedding an ng-controller directive in another
ng-controller directive and the code to unregister our handlers was in parent
ng-controller, the code would not get executed until the parent controller was
destroyed, which will not work in this case